# Adaptive streaming - smoothstreaming doesn't works

Tags: android, video-streaming, google-tv

From documentation: "Adaptive Streaming - Automatically adapts to either congestion or bandwidth availability". But this works only when player starts (I use VideoView). If the intrenet speed falls while playing video - nothing happens but it is preferable that player switch video quality base on curren internte speed. So, questions:

Does android video player supports switching video quality in real time while playing video?
If yes, how to implement this?

Thank you for your attention.

**Update:** 
For example Youtube google tv app. If bandwidth changing while playing video, player automaticaly switches to appropriate video quality without any delays.

What I have to do to make it work? I am using VideoView and it is works only when I start player.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying 'speed falls' that the internet bandwidth becomes less over time?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would implement your own subclass of the VideoView that utilizes some form of QoS to monitor network bandwidth. If you are working on a Google TV application you can use the GtvVideoView (which supports smoothstreaming). To understand more about this you can read up on it here: https://developers.google.com/tv/android/articles/hls?hl=en

Comment: I am working on google tv application, but what do you mean "use the GtvVideoView" - I am using VideoView. And as I say, when I set to the player videosteam - it is choose steam according to my bandwidth, but if while playing video my bandwidth becomes less nothing happens, only when I restart player - video choosen according to the current bandwidth.

Comment: I would probably recommend extending MediaPlayer; it gives you more low level access to settings, media events and error handling. You can change the player behavior to your needs. MediaPlayer can handle HLS streams itself. VideoView is a wrapper for MediaPlayer.